# I have a JavaScript function that calls a PHP Function. How can I get the results to display in the html and not in an alert box?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I have a PHP function that makes a cURL call to an API. I want this call to be triggered by the click of a button using JavaScript. How can I get the result to display in the HTML and not in an alert box? My code is as follows:

```
<script>
        function echoSkilljar() {
            alert("<?php skilljarApiCall(); ?>");
        }
        </script>

    <?php
        function skilljarApiCall() {
            // Get cURL resource
            $curl = curl_init();

            // Set some options - passing a username to Skilljar in the URL
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.skilljar.com/v1/users/***********/published-courses',
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
                CURLOPT_USERNAME => 'sk-live-***********'
                ));

                // Send the Request & save response to $response
                $response = curl_exec($curl);

                // Close request to clear up some resources
                curl_close($curl);

                // Trim response string to remove leading and trailing "[ and ]"
                $trimmed = trim($response, '"[');
                $newTrimmed = rtrim($trimmed, ']"');

                // Convert trimmed string to JSON
                $json = json_encode($newTrimmed);

                // Convert JSON to usable associative array
                $newJson = json_decode($json);
                $array = json_decode($newJson, true);

                // Make sure it worked... (fingers crossed);
                // var_dump($array);

                // Yay it worked! Now make sure we can access the elements of the array...
                echo $array['course']['id'] . "/ " . $array['course']['title'];
        }   
    ?>

    <button onclick="echoSkilljar()">Skilljar Stuff</button>
    <div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Comment: you cant call a php function from js like that ... lookup AJAX

Comment: @rtfm Actually, you can, but it'll echo the value out so the returned HTML basically has the string hard-coded.

Comment: @samanime i suspect that's not the result he is wanting ;)

Comment: after you use `AJAX` instead of what you have, on ajax success you should manipulate the DOM, you can read w3schools javascript tutorial or you can see MDN docs

Comment: @rtfm He mentioned that it works when alerted and wants to put it in the HTML instead. I think this actually just boils down to a simple JS problem with some PHP in there as a red herring. If he does want to do it in real-time on click, then indeed he'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: @samanime the problem with what he has now is that the curl call shall be made possibly taking precious time whether the button is clicked or not but OP apparently would like the curl call to not happen until button click

Comment: @niceman, I didn't even think of that. I said in a reply to your comment below that I understood but after reflecting on it some more and reading this comment I realize there was a gap in my logic. So...back to the drawing board. Always learning! I will explore the AJAX route. Thank you for the constructive critique and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, this part:

```
<script>
    function echoSkilljar() {
        alert("<?php skilljarApiCall(); ?>");
    }
</script>
```

basically gets resolved to some fixed string. Let's assume the result is `my-output`. That means your HTML looks like this when rendered:

```
<script>
    function echoSkilljar() {
        alert("my-output");
    }
</script>
```

So, in this case, we're just talking about how to make a simple string output in the HTML.

There are a large number of ways you could go about this. You didn't specify, but I'm going to assume you wanted to put it inside of the `<div id="info"></div>`.

To do that, we'll just select it and set it's `innerText`.

```html
<script>
  function echoSkilljar() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerText = "my-content";
  }
</script>

<button onClick="echoSkilljar()">Click Me</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Basically, just replace this line:

```
alert("<?php skilljarApiCall(); ?>");
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById('info').innerText = "<?php skilljarApiCall(); ?>";
```

When rendered, it'll look like this:

```
document.getElementById('info').innerText = "my-content";
```

Comment: @JeffreyMobley ok just know the API call is made on every page load, NOT, every button press

Comment: Yes, I understand.